# Posting a Document as per ApiDoc always fails with error 400

Tags: rest-api, document, fileupload

I have taken the Api Documentation for uploading a document to SalesForce.

After trying to get it to work in my usual programming language and failing I have decided to try it directly in the console, identically to the example and I can't get it to work.

Is the endpoint not in use anymore? Is the documentation wrong? I always get the 400 Error.

[The Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm)

At the Moment of writing it states:

[image]

My call:

```
curl https://myInst.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Document/ -H "Authorization: Bearer myToken" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=\"b4e92a3ddb6ca8cb\"" --data-binary @t.json
```

My body:

```
--b4e92a3ddb6ca8cb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_document";
Content-Type: application/json
 
{"Description":"Ein Invoice Template","Keywords":"In, Voice","FolderId":"0010900000DUnNOAA1","Name":"Invoice Template","Type":"txt"}
 
--b4e92a3ddb6ca8cb
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Body"; filename="empty.txt"
 
My Text File Content
 
--b4e92a3ddb6ca8cb--
```

No matter what I try, even without body completely, wrong body, right body, different files, no avail...

Can somebody enlighten me?